# Component/design recommendations for high power RF switch IC for 1-50 MHz

Tags: switches, rf, circuit-design, solid-state-relay, solid-state-devices

In trying to design the circuit, I've been researching the components that are available, and most appear to be focused on the 1-4 GHz range, but some work with lower frequencies.

Is there a solid state component (perhaps an RF switch IC?) that will handle 1KW at HF frequencies? The closest I've found is the SKY12208-306LF which only handles 50W so many would need to be combined.

datasheet: http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/SKY12208_306LF_202077C.pdf

The need for the RF switch is to switch in and out inductors and capacitors in an L network.  Most designs seem to use relays, but I wanted to investigate solid state switching options.

Comment: You haven't linked the datasheet and it's not clear what you mean by "handling" 50W. But if it can *dissipate* 50W, it may be able to *switch* much higher powers, as long as the power wasted inside it remains below 50W.

Comment: Power rating it not entirely the right metric. You may be trying to deliver 1kW of power to something, but you aren't trying to dissipate 1kW of power in the switch. What are the corresponding voltage/current specifications/requirements?

Comment: Use relays! 1kW @ 50ohm is about 5A and 250V but then talking of "switching in/out L or C" we are in automatic tuners field. In this case Q can rise above quantities several folds.

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to the datasheet, hoping this adds some clarity to the power dissipation question.  Not sure what power dissipation means in the context of a switch like this.  I was thinking it analogous to a piece of wire, and the amount of power that the wire can handle before melting, but perhaps this is not the correct meaning.

@BrianDrummond, if you have any clarifying thoughts based on the datasheet I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: ^^ CC @TomCarpenter

Comment: @carloc I was hoping to iterate through tens of thousands of combinations of switched components far faster than relays would permit.   I take it there is not a solid state device that offers comparable benefits to a relay for power handling?

Comment: @DaveTweed please unflag my question as I have updated it to clarify that I am looking for a recommendation for a class of device to use not a purchase recommendation.

Comment: No, A.F.A.I.K there are no such devices. Now some guessing: All automatic antenna tuners I have seen is made out of relays or motor driven variable capacitor and variometer . When tuning a relatively short (hence capacitive) antenna at low frequency is not uncommon to have a few kV RF @200W already. On the other hand tuning algorithms do not have to run thru all combinations of relays, it can be more an \$ \propto  N\$than a \$ \propto 2^N \$ process. And finally you can measure input frequency and first try *"last known good"* relay combination  next time you have that same frequency again.

Comment: OK it won't switch powers over 50W. And the datasheet doesn't say anything about its performance below 20MHz at all...

Comment: Still haven't added information about the current/voltage specifications of your load.

Comment: It will be RF at 100W, under 30 MHz, with SWR up to 60:1

Answer (score 1):

PIN diodes with suitable biasing arrangements?

The low frequency end may be the difficult one to source here as it needs diodes with very long carrier lifetimes (at least several microseconds at 1MHz), MACOM have suitable parts.

Not a cheap option, and I would note that if this is for something like LPF switching then relays can be highly reliable as they should never have occasion to switch under load, and mechanical latching ones will reduce your idle power requirements, relays are also pretty much imune to static discharge which cannot be said of PIN switches.

Have a look at the circuit for that MFJ QSK board for ideas.

73

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have looked at the MFJ QSK board and had been considering using that design, but then it occurred to me that perhaps a component had been designed that essentially packaged up the PIN diode for RF switching... 

The MFJ device uses several PIN diodes, so I imagine for my use case (switching in/out 20+ inductors or capacitors) it would get somewhat expensive...

http://faculty.frostburg.edu/phys/latta/ee/qsk5/schematic/schematic.html